# Is a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals with free stalks of rank 1 a Cartier divisor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, neron-models

Let $X$ be a scheme and let $\mathscr{I} \subset \mathscr{O}_X$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals. Suppose that for each $x \in X$, the stalk $\mathscr{I}_x$ is generated by an element $f_x \in \mathscr{O}_x$ that comes from a nonzero divisor $f  \in \Gamma(U, \mathscr{O}_X)$ for some affine open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ (so $f_x$ is a nonzero divisor, too). Then each $\mathscr{I}_x$ is a free $\mathscr{O}_x$-module of rank $1$. Is $\mathscr{I}$ necessarily locally free of rank $1$?

The answer is surely 'yes' if $X$ is Noetherian (e.g., by http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AG8), but a positive answer is claimed in general in the last paragraph on p. 212 of the book "Neron models". Is there a counterexample to this claim?

Comment: The authors simply forgot to assume that $\mathscr{I}$ is of finite presentation as an $O_X$-module. What ultimately matters is Lemma 6 on p. 213, so don't take that claim on p. 212 too seriously as written.  When you write a 300-page book on technically difficult mathematics, good luck making no harmless minor glitches like that. :)

Comment: Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, chap. II, § 5, exercise 7. As indicated in the previous comment, the answer is also 'yes' with no noetherian hypothesis if $\mathscr{I}$ is finitely presented (loc. cit., Proposition 2).

Comment: @user74230:  Is there an erratum for that book?  I love that book, and I direct my advisees to read it.  If there are mistakes (apparently quite a few, according to Question Mark), I would like to know what they are.

Comment: @JasonStarr: I'm not aware of an erratum, but the rate of errors is no different than other books of comparable length/level and (as you know) its handling of technical issues is masterfully clean.  I don't know why Q.M. posts so many questions about this book, since most of those "errors" do not affect anything of interest (e.g., the above incorrect "claim") and are easily bypassed. I noticed all of these when reading the book as a student and never found them to be a hindrance to understanding.

Comment: @user74230:  Thanks for the reply.  I have also never had a student so confused by any point in the book that we could not work out the solution in a few minutes.  However, students are often confused by small issues, and it would make sense to collect those.  I also find Question Mark curious, but if the final result is a thorough erratum, what is the harm?

Comment: @user74230: I agree, but a conterexample would nevertheless be an interesting thing to have (to complement other known pathologies in algebraic geometry). By the way, for latter purposes Lemma 6 on p. 213 needs to be upgraded (same proof): $\mathscr{I}$ should only be assumed of loc. finite type and, in (i), invertible at a *neighborhood* of $x$ (with the parenthetical pertaining only to the finite presentation case). This "upgrade" is needed on p. 215 to get $\mathrm{Div}_{X/S}$ an *open* subfunctor of $\mathrm{Hilb}_{X/S}$ ($D$ there being f.p. only means that $\mathscr{I}_D$ is of f.t.).

Comment: @JasonStarr: Certainly no harm. I'm just puzzled why these are being posted so often individually on MO rather than compiled as a single document and discussed once afterwards (to have more perspective on what is important).  There are small harmless errors like the above in many standard books (e.g., Hartshorne's AG textbook) and it isn't clear that posting questions about them one-by-one on MO is appropriate.

Comment: @QM: I agree fully about the value of recording "known pathologies"; you may wish to consider suggesting that deJong include this one about the invertible ideal sheaves in his Museum of Horrors (aka the chapter Examples) in the Stacks Project.  In Lemma 6, with $\mathscr{I}$ just finite type, (i) is OK as written since *$S$-flatness* of $D$ at $x$ and f.p. over $S$ for $D$ and lfp for $X$ over $S$ force $\mathscr{I}$ to be f.p. over $O_X$ by "descent to the noetherian case" (by openness of flatness for lfp maps, such as $D\rightarrow S$).

Comment: @user74230: I post these questions because I think it is useful for potential further readers or aficionados of the book to be aware of the small errors present and modifications that need to be made. Most of these are harmless, but some are genuinely confusing or somewhat serious gaps (not this one in particular); most would also be overlooked by most readers. Since these "questions" are so specific that many readers may not have a real person to consult with (most people can't be bothered about small details anyway), why not have them available on MO (I can't think of a better medium)?

Comment: @JasonStarr: I have posted all the more serious glitches that I have noticed while reading. The ones I have not posted are either typos or modifications to some proofs needed to fix minor glitches (I haven't posted the latter because they don't affect the validity of any Theorems/Propositions). Overall, as you know, this book is very solid in all aspects, especially, in handling highly technical details, and there are very few errors.

Comment: @user74230: It would be good to have this included in SP where you suggest, but first someone needs to come up with a counterexample (which is what I was hoping for with this question; I've tried inventing one, but didn't succeed). Thanks for the comment about (i) of Lemma 6.

Comment: @QuestionMark: To make the MO postings more useful for future users seeking such stuff I recommend that you put the label "neron-models" for all of these questions (not just "algebraic-geometry"); I haven't looked back at the earlier ones but this one is only labeled with ag, but I think such a heron-models tag does exist.

Comment: @user74230: That's a good idea! I'll add the neron-models tag to all my questions about the book. (I hope these phantom edits won't result in too much spam on top of the site.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CW answer to get this of the unanswered list. Answered in the comments:

> **user74230:** The authors simply forgot to assume that I is of finite presentation as an OX-module. What ultimately matters is Lemma 6 on p. 213, so don't take that claim on p. 212 too seriously as written. When you write a 300-page book on technically difficult mathematics, good luck making no harmless minor glitches like that. :)

> **abx:** Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra, chap. II, § 5, exercise 7. As indicated in the previous comment, the answer is also 'yes' with no noetherian hypothesis if I is finitely presented (loc. cit., Proposition 2).